# SQLte3 вывод данных

Tags: python

Всем привет, имеется запрос SQL который выводит телеграмм бот пользователю. Как вывести всю информацию с бд вот в таком ввиде пользователю? (Есть URL,текст) [image: Так выглядит желаемый итоговый результат]

А сейчас я получаю данные в таком ввиде [image: Что я получаю на данном этапе]

функция SQL запроса ниже, спасибо за обратную связь!

```
def select_res():
    with sq.connect("data_pars.db") as db:
        cur = db.cursor()
        Sel_products = cur.execute("SELECT URL_id, text FROM vk_post WHERE status = False").fetchall()
        db.commit()
        return Sel_products
```

P.S Как отредактировать текст чтобы убрать \n?

Comment: SQL-то тут при чём? Информация уже пришла на питона, и, как показывает скрин, нормально. Вы просто не умеете её отформатировать. Уберите лишний тег..

Comment: Судя по всему вы прямо полученный список из выборки, не разбирая, отправляете пользователю. Ну он и показывается как питоновский список кортежей значений полей БД.

Comment: @CrazyElf я пытаюсь его разобрать но безуспешно

Comment: Так разбирать список надо в коде бота, а его вы в вопросе не показали.

Comment: @CrazyElf Разве нельзя разобрать его после запроса SQL?

Comment: @CrazyElf Я передаю данную функцию боту для отправки этих данных

Comment: В списке несколько результатов. Если бот ожидает от вашей функции один результат, как вы его заставите отправить несколько результатов? Нужно связку с ботом менять.